# Hypothesis clarification for: $G$ be a group have all normal subgroups. If $a, b \in G,$ prove that there is an integer $k$ such that $ab=ba^{k}$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

For the following question, can I assume that all the  normal subgroups of $G$ are cyclic?

> Let $G$ be a group all of whose subgroups are normal.  IF $a, b \in G,$ prove that there is an integer $k$ such that $ab=ba^{k}$

Earlier in the exercises, the author ask the reader to do the following exercise below which I have done.  I try to find online criteria for a normal subgroup to be cyclic, but was not able to do so.  Also, if I can assume that the normal groups are cyclic, then the question is very similar to the the earlier one.

> Prove that a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is normal if and only if it has this property: $ab \in N$ if and only if $ba \in N,$ for all $a,b\in G$. Prove that the cyclic subgroup $\left <a\right>$ of a group $G$ is normal if and only if for each $g\in G,$ $ga=a^{k}g$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't assume the normal subgroups are all cyclic, but you can assume the cyclic subgroups are all normal. Isn't that what you want to use?

Comment: @GerryMyerson how can I assume that assume the cyclic subgroups are all normal?  Can I have a situation where none of the subgroups of $G$ are cyclic but the subgroups themselves are all normal?

Comment: If you're assuming that *all* subgroups of $G$ are normal, then you know $\big<a\big>$ is normal so taking $g=b^{-1}$ in your second statement yields $b^{-1}a=a^kb^{-1}$ for some $k$.

Comment: The hypothesis is that ALL the subgroups are normal, so surely the cyclic subgroups are normal. And every group has cyclic subgroups, because every element of $G$ generates a cyclic subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I can show that every group has cyclic subgroups as follows:  Every group is isomorphic to a permutation group, and hence every permutation group has cyclic subgroups, hence every group has cyclic subgroups.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Shaun thank you for editing my posts.  I am getting better at latex, hopefully

Comment: No, that's not correct. How do you get "hence, every permutation group has cyclic subgroups"? Anyway, I already told you why every group has cyclic subgroups.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I forgot to add that if the group is of finite order. and is isomorphic to a permutation group, then the permutation group has at least one cyclic subgroup..  Also every group has at least two cyclic subgroups, the trivial subgroup and the group itself.  And thank you for the answer.  I forgot of these  little facts.

Comment: "every group has at least two cyclic subgroups, the trivial subgroup and the group itself," That's not true. Most groups are not cyclic. You need to review the basics.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ops, thank you for catching the typo. I mean two subgroups.

Comment: That's not right; otherwise, every group would be cyclic.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the point: "the group itself" is usually not a cyclic subgroup, unless the group happens to be cyclic. As I said: you really need to review the basics, as you seem to be very shaky on them.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin somehow when I hear the two words groups and cyclic, I automatically think of whether the group is cyclic and forget that any element in a group, by repeating the group operation element to it, i eventually get the identity and hence forms a cyclic subgroup and that doesn't imply that the group itself is cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

You can't necessarily assume that if a group has all normal subgroups, then they are all cyclic. However, you can work with the assumption that any cyclic subgroup is normal. Let $N = \langle a \rangle$. Take any $b \in G$, and show that $ab = ba_1$ for some $a_1 \in N$. Since $N$ is cyclic, what does this say about the relation between $a_1$ and the generator $a$? The conclusion should quickly follow after.